# Multiple hypothesis testing correction is subjective?

Tags: multiple-comparisons

I am currently trying to understand the concept of p-value correction, because it seems very subjective.

Here is one example: Let's say we have a classic control vs treatment experiment, in which we are testing the effects of a given drug in gene expression. Two researchers working on the exact same samples test the same hypothesis, except researcher A uses a newer technology that allows him to measure 30,000 genes at once and researcher B uses an older technology that measure 50 genes.

Now, after correcting the p-value all 50 genes measured by researcher B are significant, however the same is not true for the same 50 genes for researcher A because of the number of testing.

My question is: How can it be scientifically accurate for researcher B to claim that the drug significantly affect the expression of these 50 genes, but researcher A cannot claim it, even though the experiment where conducted on the same samples? Even worse, researcher A is "penalized" by providing a more comprehensive view of the problem.